# Segmentation fault при добавлении объекта в unordered_map

Tags: c++

Столкнулся с такой проблемой, мне необходимо записать абстрактный класс в unordered_map для дальнейшего использования. Однако, при попытке это сделать постоянно получаю segmentation fault.

```
class Form {
protected:
    const char *title;
public:
    explicit Form(const char *title) {
        this->title = title;
    }    

    virtual const char *getType() const = 0;    

    const char *getTitle() const {
        return title;
    }    

    string jsonSerialize();    

    virtual void serializeFormData(JsonWriter &writer) {}
};    

class MenuForm : public Form {
protected:
    const char *text;
    const vector<Button *> buttons;
public:
    explicit MenuForm(const char *title, const char *text, vector<Button *> buttons) : Form(title), text(text), buttons(std::move(buttons)) {}    

    const char *getType() const override {
        return "form";
    }    

    void serializeFormData(JsonWriter &writer) override;
};    

struct ServerPlayer : Player {
    int formIdCounter = 0;
    std::unordered_map<int, std::shared_ptr<Form>> forms;    

    void sendNetworkPacket(Packet &packet) const;    

    void sendForm(Form *form) {
        int id = formIdCounter++;    

        ModalFormRequestPacket pk{this->getClientSubId()};
        pk.formId = id;
        pk.formData = form->jsonSerialize();    

        forms.insert(std::make_pair(id, std::shared_ptr<Form>(form))); //вызывает краш   

        sendNetworkPacket(pk);
    }
}
```

Вызывается вот так:

```
auto menu = new MenuForm("test", "text", vector<Button *>{
        new Button("button #1"),
        new Button("button #2")
});

player.sendForm(menu);
```

Comment: Придраться есть к чему (в т.ч. потенциальное полиморфное удаление класса без виртуального деструктора), но прямых причин для краша имено в этой стоке не видно. Вы что-то не договариваете. Вы уверены, что краш вызывает именно эта строчка, а не `form->jsonSerialize();`?

Comment: @AnT без `forms.insert` все работает замечательно

Comment: Это еще не означает, что проблема именно в `forms.insert`.

Comment: Ну во-первых у `Form` невиртуальный деструктор, поэтому разрушение объекта `MenuForm` через указатель на `Form` приводит к неопределенному поведению. Память `buttons` утекает. Также стоит привести содержимое `ModalFormRequestPacket` и `jsonSerialize`.

Comment: @VTT https://pastebin.com/1zn1XsBR

Comment: @frago Слишком много кода (без комментариев, кстати). Напишите маленький самодостаточный пример, воспроизводящий проблему. Возможно, когда напишите, и проблема сразу найдётся. Или выложите весь проект, чтобы мы за Вас смогли его отладить (на github, например). Правда, вряд-ли этим кто-нибудь будет заниматься, но всё же.

Comment: @vegorov я пытался сделать это, но ошибка не возникала. Еще стоит отметить, что ServerPlayer как бы уже скомпилирован и является частью библиотеки, в которую мне приходится внедрять свой код.

Comment: @frago ясно. Тем не менее, как Вы утверждаете, крэш происходит при вставке новой пары значений  (при вставке!!!) в `std::unordered_map`, хотя судя по тому что Вы привели  крэша там не будет. Как Вам уже и написали - Вы что-то не договариваете. Приведите весь исходный код проекта или придумайте маленький простой пример, воспроизводящий проблему. Может библиотека с ошибками ?

Comment: @vegorov Я имею ввиду ошибку выделения памяти. Мб вместо map память выделена под что-то другое. Поэтому, для решения проблемы нужно чем-то залить память через `char filler[size]` или вынести unordered_map за пределы класса

Comment: Form, это абстрактный класс (имеет чистую виртуальную функцию).  Вы же пишете конструктор для него, наследуете от конкретного  обьекта..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему банальным переносом `std::unordered_map` в другой класс.